# Explanation for a Data from Treasury Direct

Tags: data, treasury

I am dealing with a treasury data from TreasuryDirect. Due to the lack of documentation, I am having a hard time understand the meaning of the variables. It would be great help if anyone can share any of your knowledge regrading concepts and differences of these variables.

- CUSIP, Announced CUSIP, Original CUSIP
- Multiples to Bid, Multiples to Issue
- Maturity date and Maturing date
- Competitive Accepted, Competitive Tendered, Competitive Bid Decimals, Competitive Tenders Accepted
- Special Announcement

Comment: In Jan 2020 a 7-year note with CUSIP 912828Z78 was auctioned https://www.treasurydirect.gov/instit/annceresult/press/preanre/2020/R_20200128_3.pdf . In Jan 22 it still had 5 years to run, the Treasury decided to issue more of this note (a reopening), and for a short time an original CUSIP 91282CDT5 was issued for the new notes. https://www.treasurydirect.gov/instit/annceresult/press/preanre/2022/R_20220125_2.pdf However the new CUSIP was then discontinued and all the notes now trade under the  912828Z78 cusip https://www.dtcc.com/-/media/Files/pdf/2022/1/25/GOV1215-22.pdf

Comment: Maturity and Maturing are synonymous. Maturity is used in reference to new securities issued, Maturing is used in reference to TBills already outstanding and the amount of them is given as Estimated Amount of Maturing Bills Held by the Public